# see network traffic for the iOS apps via Charles proxy

Tags: ios, charles-proxy, network-traffic

I've got all the settings right and I'm intercepting the SSL traffic.

The only problem is SSL handshake failing.

I've installed the Charles Proxy SSL certificate on my iPhone and marked it as trusted.

It's a 3rd party app (non apple, non google) that I'm trying to see it's traffic. Please guide.

**Network Traffic**

[image: Network Traffic]

**SSL Proxying Settings**

[image: SSL Proxying Settings]

Comment: You could use Charles' iOS app instead

Comment: @nathan Ok, so desktop version can't do it?. How was your experience with their iOS apps, can you see all the SSL traffic in plain text for 3rd party apps?

Comment: It can be done but it’s easier to use the iOS app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a 3rd party app and you don't have the source code, it can't be done. The app needs to explicitly allow the Charles SSL cert, or set "Application Transport Security > Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES in its Info.plist. The Charles iOS app may be able to do it.

Comment: yes I tried earlier and it worked with Charles iOS app